# How to get this url into code (wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress

I have got image with url field, how can i get this entry with wordpress api?

[image]

Comment: Please explain your question. To where you need to call this url? If you insert this image into a post, then you can retrieve this url through API

Comment: i want take entry of this field. for example in field url i have got "123" I want to echo this text "123" to screen. Sorry for my bad english, can you understand me? red field in photo is url field

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the url of a large image you can use this code:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    full_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send it to an input field (even if hidden).
Then use that input field value in PHP
The default one that wordpress itself uses  is jQuery :

```
    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
         imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
         jQuery('#your_input_name').val(imgurl);
         tb_remove();
        }
```